# Why is this code failing to parse a date string?

Tags: php

For this MCVE in php

```
<?
$value = "2016-08-25 (Thu) - 13:36:43";
$date=date_create_from_format("Y-m-d (a) - H:M:S",$value);
echo date_format($date, 'Y-m-d');
?>
```

I'm getting the error

```
 Warning: date_format() expects parameter 1 to be DateTimeInterface, boolean given in /home/joereddington/joereddington.com/Jurgen/webclient/temp.php on line 11
```

It's pretty clear that the date_create_from_format is failing, but I'm struggling to understand why it's failing, or how I can get it to show me an error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format is incorrect. The day is D, the minutes are i and the seconds are s. Try this:

```
$value = "2016-08-25 (Thu) - 13:36:43";
$date=date_create_from_format("Y-m-d (D) - H:i:s",$value);
var_dump($date);
echo date_format($date, 'Y-m-d');
```

More info:

http://php.net/manual/es/datetime.createfromformat.php